# How to make Clojure's `while` return a value

Tags: macros, clojure, while-loop

Can someone please explain why Clojure's `while` macro doesn't return a value?

The [documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/while) says "Presumes
some side-effect will cause test to become false/nil." Okay, so we use `swap!` to modify the atom which is used in the test case. But can't we still have a return value (perhaps returning repeatedly, as in the case with `loop`), along *with* the side effects?

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5824), it seems like the cause could be something to do with how recursion and macros work, but I don't know enough about the internals of that to speculate.

**Example**:

The following code only returns `nil`:

```
(let [a (atom 0)]
  (while (< @a 10)
    (+ 1 @a)
    (swap! a inc)))
```

That is, it does not return the value of `(+ 1 @a)`, nor does it return any other value or function that is inside the `while` loop. If we want to get some value calculated via the `while` loop, we could use `print`, but then we can't easily use the value in some other operation. For a return value, we have to use a second atom, like this:

```
(let [a (atom 0)
      end (atom 0)]
  (while (< @a 10)
    (swap! end #(+ 1 %))
    (swap! a inc))
  @end)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `(source while)` at the REPL, we can see it is implemented like this:

```
(defmacro while
  "Repeatedly executes body while test expression is true. Presumes
  some side-effect will cause test to become false/nil. Returns nil"
  {:added "1.0"}
  [test & body]
  `(loop []
     (when ~test
       ~@body
       (recur))))
```

So, it executes the body, then checks the condition, rinse, repeat. By the time the condition is false, the most recent return value from the body is gone.

But what exactly are you trying to do? Do you really need an atom for this?

This code counts up to 10 and returns 10:

```
(loop [a 0]
  (if (< a 10)
    (recur (inc a))
    a))
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. I'm comparing the values of map1 with the values of map2 in order to find a match and return array of the associated keys from map2 (basically like a lookup table). So the body is more complicated than this example. I could definitely use `loop`, but I've used `loop` like 4 times in the past day and I've never used `while`, so I wanted to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please explain why Clojure's while macro doesn't return a value?
>
> But can't we still ... along *with* the side effects?

Side effects are there for when you *need* them, but if you are too free in mixing them throughout your regular code then you are missing out on one of the huge benefits of functional programming.

In clojure.core, the 'functions' that are used for the purpose of realising some side effect are always demarcated as such and it's a good idea to follow this in your own code too.